# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to date

Tags: python, django, postgresql, deployment, django-migrations

Hello guys i have some problem with PostgreSQL when i deploy from docker.
Error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to date
[2022-06-01 09:06:04] LINE 1: ...a_playlist" ALTER COLUMN "year" TYPE date USING "year"::date
```

It's my migration file :

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('multimedia', '0004_track_track'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='playlist',
        name='year',
        field=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='track',
        name='year',
        field=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True),
    ),
]
```

How can i fix that problem ? Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, was your field originally a IntegerField ?

Comment: @Emile, yes originally IntegerField. After i'm change to DateField.

Answer (score 4):

What you encounter might be solved as follow :

Let's assume your models are :

```py
class Playlist(models.Model):
    ...
    year = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...

class Track(models.Model):
    ...
    year = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...
```

#### Remove your migration

To avoid confusion, I'd remove the migration you just created.
If you are familiar with django you might jump on the next steps and edit the `AlterField` arguments.

#### Rename your fields

Change the naming for example temp_year.

```py
class Playlist(models.Model):
    ...
    temp_year = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...

class Track(models.Model):
    ...
    temp_year = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...
```

Then run `./manage.py makemigrations`.

You have now a migration containing the renamed fields.

#### Add a proper year field

```py
class Playlist(models.Model):
    ...
    temp_year = models.IntegerField(...)
    year = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Track(models.Model):
    ...
    temp_year = models.IntegerField(...)
    year = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Then run `./manage.py makemigrations`.

You have now a migrations containing the field with the data type you want.

#### Transfer your data

In the migrations file freshly created after your last `migrations.AddField(...)`, add `migrations.RunPython()`.

some docs about RunPython are found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)

Just above the migration class add a function, let's name it `map_to_year`:

```py
import datetime
def map_to_year(apps, schema_editor):
    Playlist = apps.get_model("your_app_name", "Playlist")
    for playlist in Playlist.objects.all():
        playlist.year = datetime.date(playlist.temp_year,01,01)
        playlist.save(update_fields=["year"])

    Track = apps.get_model("your_app_name", "Track")
    for track in Track.objects.all():
        track.year = datetime.date(track.temp_year,01,01)
        track.save(update_fields=["year"])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...
    migrations.AddField(...),
    migrations.RunPython(map_to_year)
    ...
```

Note : change your_app_name with the correct one

#### Run the migrations

Now if you run the migrations it maps your integer from temp_year to a date object from year.

#### What's next ?

Once the migration pass you should be able to remove the temp_year field and run `makemigrations`